# Javafx refresh src folder

Tags: javafx, refresh

I wrote a program that each user has an account, and they can change their head portrait. When they sign in, the directory "src/username/password" will be created, and the image "src/username/password/headPortrait.jpg" will also be created. Then the default headPortrait is expected to show on a label, but the problem occurs: an image is added to the "src/username/password" directory, but the src folder in eclipse is not refreshed, so the program can't find the added image and throws Exception. So, I must exit the program ,refresh the src folder and then run the program again. That's absolutely not what I expect. What should I do about that?
Here is the most important part of my code:

```
String username=name.getText(); //"name" is a TextField
String password=word.getText(); //"word" is a TextField

File namefile=new File("src/"+username);
File passwordfile=new File("src/"+username+"/"+password);

if(namefile.mkdirs()){
    if(passwordfile.mkdirs()){
       File default=new File("src/images/headPortrait.jpg");//the default fead portrait is previously put under this directory.

        try{
           FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(default);
           FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("src/"+username+"/"+password+"/"+"headPortrait.jpg");
           BufferedInputStream bufferedIn=new BufferedInputStream(in);
           BufferedOutputStream bufferedOut=new BufferedOutputStream(out);
           byte[] bytes=new byte[1];
           while(bufferedIn.read(bytes)!=-1){
               bufferedOut.write(bytes);
           }
           bufferedOut.flush();
           bufferedIn.close();
           bufferedOut.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       //Here, the problem aready occurs! The folders and default                     
       //portrait are successfully created but the src folder in eclipse 
       //is not refreshed, so the default portrait won't show up!
    }else{
        //show a failure message
    }
}else{
    //show a failure message
}

Label portrait=new Label();
ImageView userImage=new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass.getResouceAsStream("/"+username+"/"+password+"/"+headPortrait.jpg)));
portrait.setGraphic(userImage);
//And the userImage won't show up and throws Exception, because the src folder in eclipse is not refreshed!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the approach you should use since it will would only work in the development environment. When you deploy your app the compiled code will most likely be contained in a `.jar` archive that the JVM accesses.

The way to go would be to store the data in a convenient place (server, user directory, ...) and load it from this source.

#### Example (user directory)

```
static Path appDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).toPath().resolve("myapp");

static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream bufferedIn=new BufferedInputStream(in);
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOut=new BufferedOutputStream(out);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while(bufferedIn.read(bytes)!=-1){
        bufferedOut.write(bytes);
    }
}
```

```
String username=name.getText(); //"name" is a TextField
String password=word.getText(); //"word" is a TextField

Path passwordDirectory = appDirectory.resolve(Paths.get(username, password));
Path userImage = passwordDirectory.resolve("headPortrait.jpg");

Files.createDirectories(passwordDirectory);
try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/headPortrait.jpg");   // make sure this image is included as resource
     OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(userImage)) {
    copy(in, out);
}
```

```
ImageView userImageView = new ImageView(new Image(userImage.toUri().toString()));
```

---

**BTW:** Creating a directory from user name and password seems to be a bad idea to me. The password may contain characters that must not be part of a file name after all... Also it would require you to move the files when the the password is changed... Not to mention the password is stored as plain text in a prominent place...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As for the problem you mentioned in the BTW, what about generating a unique and unchangeable user ID for every user, and use the ID as the name of the user's folder. And I will store the username and password in a txt file under the user's folder. So the username and password can be easily modified. Will that be OK?